# Random Multinomial Variable

Tags: random-variables

Nine persons go into a 3-carriage tram. Each person chooses the carriage at
random. Which are the probabilities of the event: A :
“There are 4 person in a carriage, 3 in another, and 2 in the other one”?

The answer should be $\frac{280}{729}$

Comment: Hint: What is your sample space? How many ways are there to arrange 9 people in 3 carriages?

Comment: $\frac{9!}{4! 3! 2!} \cdot (\frac{4}{9})^4 \cdot(\frac{3}{9})^3\cdot(\frac{2}{9})^2$ but I think I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is $$\frac{\frac {9!}{4!3!2!}}{3^9}=0.0640146...$$